# Rmarkdown not including Shiny plots in a loop

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, plotly

I have plotly objects stored in a list. I have a rmarkdown and am including shiny app to call the plotly objects. I am getting error:- Error in [[: subscript out of bounds  [No stack trace available]. But when I am running actual code I am getting error:- Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'ggplotly' applied to an object of class "NULL"  [No stack trace available].

I am not using ggplotly anywhere. So why that error.

---

````
title: "Untitled"
author: "drishti"
date: "9/26/2018"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
ggp1 <- plot_ly(iris,x = ~Sepal.Length, 
                y = ~Sepal.Width, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers',color =~ Species,
                colors = c('olivedrab3', "plum", "palegreen4"))%>%
  layout(

    xaxis = list(title = "Sepal.Length"),
    yaxis = list(title = "Sepal.Width")
  )

plot1 <- list(c("Sepal.Length"),ggp1)

ggp2 <- plot_ly(iris,x = ~Petal.Length, 
                y = ~Petal.Width, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers',color =~ Species,
                colors = c('olivedrab3', "plum", "palegreen4"))%>%
  layout(

    xaxis = list(title = "Petal.Length"),
    yaxis = list(title = "Petal.Width")
  )

plot2 <- list(c("Petal.Length"),ggp2)

model_list <- list(plot1,plot2)

```

## Embedded Application


```{r chunk1a, echo = FALSE,out.width = '8000px', out.height='800px'}
sample_data = function(dataset_name,given_model_list) {

  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      fluidRow(style = "padding-bottom: 20px;",
               selectInput(inputId="Var_Sel", label="Variables to view", choices=c("Sepal.Length","Petal.Length"), selected = c("Sepal.Length"),
                           multiple = FALSE,selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL),
               # fluidRow(plotOutput('myplot')),
               fluidRow(column(12,div(plotlyOutput("myplot", width = "100%", height = "200%",inline = F)),align="right"))
      )
    ),


    server = function(input, output, session) {

      output$myplot <- renderPlotly({

        if(is.null(input$Var_Sel)==FALSE){
          for(i in 1:ncol(dataset_name)){
            if(given_model_list[[i]][[1]] == input$Var_Sel){
              print(given_model_list[[i]][[2]])
            }
            # else(given_model_list[[1]][[2]])
          }
        }
      })

    }
  )
}
```


```{r chunk1b, echo = FALSE,out.width = '8000px', out.height='800px'}
sample_data(iris,model_list)
```
````

Comment: solved it.... Had to change the for loop .

Comment: Can you post your solution?